# How to use regular expression to find the key from filename and get value by key from hash?

Tags: perl, hash

I have one hash with few key-values, and I have 2 different kinds of filename expression, the key is inside of filename. I need to get key from filename then use key to get value from hash. 
For example

```
my $file1 = "MYCOM_SYS_ACCOUNT_20211212000001_00001.txt";<BR>
my $file2 = "MYCOM_SYS_20211211_BILLPROFILE_20211212000001_00032.txt";
```

From above filenames, the keys are ACCOUNT and BILLPROFILE. So how to extract it from single expression ? then I can search it from my hash

```
my %hashmap = ( 'ACCOUNT'=>'account', 'BILLPROFILE'=>'billprofile', 'PAYMENTTERM'=>'paymentterm',....about 1000 key-values);
```

anyone understands what my question is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```perl
my $alt = join "|", map quotemeta, keys %hashmap;
my $re = qr/_($alt)_/;

if ( my ($key) = $file =~ $re ) {
   my $val = $hashmap{$key};
   ...
}
```